# Select records in table A with *only* certain corresponding records in table B

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery, self-join

For example, say you have a table of files and a logging table of transfer operations.

```
CREATE TABLE files
(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
  -- various other columns
);

CREATE TABLE transfers
(
  id      INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  file_id INTEGER,
  status  TEXT NOT NULL,
  -- various other columns
  FOREIGN KEY (file_id) REFERENCES files (id)
)
```

A transfer operation can have various statuses -- `'succeeded'`, `'failed'`, `'in progress'`, etc. One file can have many transfer operations -- in particular, if a transfer fails, another transfer for that file may be scheduled later.

Now, say we want to find all the files with *only* failed transfers -- no transfers currently in progress, no later successful transfers.

So far I have the solution below with subselects:

```
SELECT files.*
FROM files
WHERE files.id IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT file_id
  FROM transfers
  WHERE transfers.status == 'failed'
) AND files.id NOT IN (
  SELECT DISTINCT file_id
  FROM transfers
  WHERE transfers.status <> 'failed'
)
```

However, this feels a little clunky and procedural. Is there a more elegant solution, possibly involving self-joins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use self joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT files.*
FROM
  files INNER JOIN transfers t1
  ON files.id = t1.file_id AND t1.status='failed'
  LEFT JOIN transfers t2
  ON file.id = t2.file_id AND t2.status<>'failed'
WHERE
  t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: This also seems to be the fastest solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

How about an aggregation with a `having` clause?

```
select t.file_id
from transfers t
group by t.file_id
having sum(case when status <> 'failed' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

If there is additional information from `files` that you want, you can `join` it in.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use negated `exists` for these kinds of queries as they tend to perform fine with proper indices and in my opinion reflects the intent (or semantics) or the query well.

```
SELECT file_id
FROM transfers t
WHERE t.status = 'failed'
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM transfers
    WHERE status <> 'failed'
      AND file_id = t.file_id
);
```