# ActiveRecord equivalent of messy self-join

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sqlite, self-join

Given the following models:

```rb
class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :transfers
end

class Transfer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :file
  enum status: [:pending, :in_progress, :succeeded, :failed]
end
```

Now, I want to find those `Files` that have `:failed` `Transfers`, and *only* `:failed` `Transfers`. (One `File` can have many `Transfers` -- in particular, if a transfer operation fails, another transfer for that file may be scheduled later, and might succeed.)

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32083685/27358) and some experimentation, the following SQL query seems to be the fastest way to do this:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT files.*
FROM
  files INNER JOIN transfers t1
  ON files.id = t1.file_id AND t1.status = 3   -- 3 = :failed
  LEFT JOIN transfers t2
  ON files.id = t2.file_id AND t2.status <> 3  -- 3 = :failed
WHERE
  t2.id IS NULL
```

Now, obviously I can use this directly with `find_by_sql`, but it seems like there ought to be a way to code it with the [ActiveRecord query interface](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and get the same result, *without* any raw SQL or SQL fragments. I'm thinking something like:

```rb
File.joins(:transfers).where(transfers: { status: 3 })
  .not.includes(transfer).where('status <> 3')
```

-- but you can't use `.not` there, plus it still includes a SQL fragment, and I'm not really sure of the `includes()` semantics in any case.

Maybe the AR query interface just isn't powerful enough to do what I want?